# Unable to edit and write information to a new file using Awk and Sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

As part of my homework, I need to take a row containing address information from a text file.

Like This.

```
2 GO MOBILITY / CALEX EXPRESS^58 PITTSTON AVENUE^^PITTSTON^PA^18640^570-603-1042
```

Then format the file to look like this.

```
Company Name: 2 GO MOBILITY / CALEX EXPRESS
Company Phone Number: 570-603-1042
Company Address: 58 PITTSTON AVENUE, PITTSTON, PA, 18640
\n (blank line)
```

Then append the address to a file called `PA_595.txt` within the directory `./basefolder/PA`.

If a different state is listed then the information should appear in the file in the appropriate folder.

I need to use AWK and SED to do this.

```
awk -v FS=^ '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' "./data/595.txt" | sed i\ " Company Name: $1 \n Company Address: $2,$3,$4,$5 \n Company Phone Number: $6" | tee "./$2/$5/${5}_595.txt"
```

I'm getting

```
PERFORMANCE MOBILITY 1640 WEST 7th AVE  EUGENE OR 97402 541-393-8474
Company Name:
Company Addess: ,,,
Company Phone Number:
```

I need

```
Company Name:PERFORMANCE MOBILITY
Company Phone Number:541-393-8474
Company Address: 1640 WEST 7th AVE, EUGENE, OR, 97402
```

The awk portion of the code works.  I'm pretty sure the issue is that sed isn't seeing the field names from awk.

I've made progress since last night.  I changed my code to .

```
file_name=$1
i=0

while IFS=^ read company_name address1 address2 city state zip phone
do
    ((i++))

echo "./$2/$state/${state}_595.txt"

sed -e "i\ Company Name:$company_name \n Company Phone Number:$phone \n Company Addess: $address1, $city, $state, $zip \n " | tee "./$2/$state/${state}_595.txt"


done < $file_name
```

The problem is that it shows each address as it shows in the txt file.  But then it shows it properly underneath.

>
PERFORMANCE MOBILITY^1640 WEST 7th AVE^^EUGENE^OR^97402^541-393-8474
 Company Name:2 GO MOBILITY / CALEX EXPRESS
 Company Phone Number:570-603-1042
 Company Addess: 58 PITTSTON AVENUE, PITTSTON, PA, 18640

However, the formatting is incorrect in the txt file and all address go to the same txt file.

> Company Name:2 GO MOBILITY / CALEX EXPRESS 
>    Company Phone Number:570-603-1042

Company Addess: 58 PITTSTON AVENUE, PITTSTON, PA, 18640

A & J MOBILITY^3058 HELSAN DR^^RICHFIELD^WI^53716^262-623-6236
 Company Name:2 GO MOBILITY / CALEX EXPRESS 
 Company Phone Number:570-603-1042

Company Addess: 58 PITTSTON AVENUE, PITTSTON, PA, 18640

A TO Z MOBILITY AND MEDICAL EQUIPMENT, INC.^P.O. BOX 99^^SOMONAUK^IL^60552^815-495-3423
 Company Name:2 GO MOBILITY / CALEX EXPRESS 
 Company Phone Number:570-603-1042

I'm not sure why.

The last response got me almost all the way there.  I'm just left seeing one error.

>
tee: /CA_595.txt: Permission denied

I've checked the folder and file permissions and they are all 775.

I'm using this command when creating the .txt file

```
cstates=($(awk -v FS=^ '{print $5}' "$1"))

for i in "${cstates[@]}"
do

    :

if [[ ! -f "./$2/$i/${i}_595.txt" ]]; then

    echo "Making ${i}_595.txt File"
    touch "./$2/$i/${i}_595.txt"
    chmod a+x "./$2/$i/${i}_595.txt"
    else echo "File ${i}_595.txt already exists"


fi
done
```

Or if I just use this command.

```
file_name="$1"

while IFS=^ read -r company_name address1 address2 city state zip phone
do

# sed " a\ Company Name:$company_name \n Company Phone Number:$phone \n Company Addess: $address1, $city, $state, $zip \n " | tee -a "./$2/$state/${state}_595.txt"

printf "Company Name: %s\nCompany Address: %s%s, %s, %s, %s\nCompany Phone Number: %s\n\n" \
      "${company_name}" "${address1}" "${address2}" "${city}" "${state}" "${zip}" "${phone}" | tee -a "${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt" > /dev/null


done < $file_name
```

The file and folder permission look ok and it shows me as having ownership of the files and folders.

Comment: FYi `folder` is a Windows term. The UNIX term for a file that contains other files is `directory`. So far I haven't been able to figure out what it is you're trying to do, though. I think it's got something to do with creating a directory but then it seems to be talking about looking for a file already in that directory and reading the contents of a different directory (or is that meant to be a file?) looking for a state abbreviation... It's just a bit too vague and confusing for me to try to answer so far!

Comment: I think it'd help clarify what you're trying to do if you [edit] the question to clean up the use of the words folder, directory, and file (and "directory file"). Also replace the word `build` in the first bullet list with `create` or `update` or whatever it is you mean there. And make sure to change `Read the input folder` to `Read the input file` or `Check the input directory` or whatever you meant. Basically, just make your requirements clear and relatively precise.

Comment: **bash:** `while IFS=^ read -a line; do mkdir -p "${line[1]}/${line[4]}"; printf "Company Name: %s\nCompany Address: %s\nCompany Address 2: %s,%s,%s\nCompany Zip: %s\nCompany Phone Number: %s\n" "${line[@]}" >> "./${line[1]}/${line[4]}/${line[4]}_595.txt"; done < data`

Comment: Using 

awk -v FS=^ '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' "./data/595.txt" | sed i\ " Company Name: $1 \n Company Addess: $2,$3,$4,$5 \n Company Phone Number: $6" | tee "./$2/$5/${5}_595.txt"

I'm getting this for all addresses.

PERFORMANCE MOBILITY 1640 WEST 7th AVE  EUGENE OR 97402 541-393-8474
Company Name:
 Company Addess: ,,,
 Company Phone Number:

Comment: You have two states — OR and PA — in different samples.  How is the name `PA_595.txt` created?  Is the same name used in Oregon?  The `tee` command does not have access to the variables inside `awk`; neither does `sed`.  You should probably use Awk alone; it is sufficient for the job and I seen no benefit and some disadvantages to using `sed` as well (and it doesn't bear thinking about to use `sed` alone).  Is using Awk alone sufficient, or must you use `sed` too?

Comment: Is the name `PA_595.txt` based in part on the input file `./data/595.txt` and in part on the state.  So if the OR data also came from `./data/595.txt`, then it would create `OR_595.txt` (in `./basefolder/OR`).  Can we assume that all state sub-directories have been created in `./basefolder`, or does the code have to create that directory too?  Since there are only 50 states plus sundry other zones (Washington DC, Puerto Rico, …), creating them all before running this code would be sensible.  You could even pre-screen the data to find the state codes and create the relevant directories.

Comment: The input file has a list of addresses from any of the 50 states.  One of the columns is for state abbreviations.  Which I use when creating the subfolder off of the base folder and when creating the file itself.  If I have an address from Texas,  then the folder is called "TX"  and the file is called TX_595.txt.  It's the same for all states.

My script is creating the correct folders and blank files already,  I just need to get the address from the data file, format it and insert it into the correct file.

The homework assignment has me using awk, sed and grep.

Comment: You never need sed and grep when you're using awk since awk.

Comment: I've made progress since last night.

I'm using the following code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't have the requirement of writing data to different files, the next command would work:

```
   awk -v FS=^ '{
      printf ("Company Name: %s\nCompany Address: %s%s, %s, %s, %s\nCompany Phone Number: %s\n\n",
        $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)
      }' "./data/595.txt"
```

When you want to send parts to different directories, you should print it inside `awk` to both the file and stdout. Look out for spaces in the name of the dir.

Using a loop is also possible. You can use `tee -a` (a=append) inside the loop.

```
file_name="$1" # Quote, look out for spaces.
i=0
# use read with option -r
while IFS=^ read -r company_name address1 address2 city state zip phone
do
   # Not used: ((i++))
   outputdir="./$2/$state"
   mkdir -p "${outputdir}"
   printf "Company Name: %s\nCompany Address: %s%s, %s, %s, %s\nCompany Phone Number: %s\n\n" \
      "${company_name}" "${address1}" "${address2}" "${city}" "${state}" "${zip}" "${phone}" | tee -a "${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt"
done < "${file_name}"
```

When you don't need to see the complete output in your commandline, you can replace `tee -a` by `>>`.